# Question mark (char 57399) added to HTML element text

Tags: java, html, utf-8, character-encoding, jsoup

I've come across a problem that seems really weird to me.

I'm scraping a website using Jsoup:

```
Elements names = doc.select(".Mod.Thm-inherit").select("h3");

for (Element e : names) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

My output is (Fantasy hockey team names, names changed for simplicity):

```
Team One ?
Team Two ?
Team Three ?
Team Four ?
Team Five ? 
//etc
```

Now the actual team names don't have the extra space or question mark. Thinking I could just replace it, I tried:

```
String str = e.text().replaceAll("\\?", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

This however still outputs the question mark at the end. I'm thinking that this might mean that it's a character that Eclipse/Java doesn't recognize. (Note: It doesn't display a �, it's really just the generic `?`)

When looking at the HTML code, there are no extra characters though:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!-- Bunch of HTML -->
<div class="Grid-u-1-2 Pend-xl"><h3 class="My-xl Ta-c Fz-lg"><a href="/hockey/27381/1">Team One</a>
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

**Edit:** I was quickly able to solve the issue by just doing a `substring` and removing the last 2 characters, but I'd still like to know why it's happening.

**Edit2:** Playing around with it more, I found that if I `(int)` cast the question mark, it gives me 57399, instead of `?`'s regular 63. So definitely some sort of unknown character issue. Just not sure why it's being added or what that character is supposed to represent.

Comment: Not enough information/context. You need to reproduce the problem with a minimal HTML/CSS and then provide that so someone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'd link to the page itself but it's only accessible after a login. Also I'd gladly produce a minimal HTML but I wouldn't even know where to start. I don't have much HTML knowledge and this particular website has a pretty complex structure. Short of providing the entire source HTML, there isn't much I can do

Comment: I was hoping this was known behaviour that someone with more experience would be able to instantly identify

Comment: Part of the problem is that with so little code in you post it's hard to tell what's going on.  For example, the `<script>` tag shouldn't have a `<div>` tag inside it, as in your HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be extra `h3` fields with strange characters inside your `".Mod.Thm-inherit"`element.

For a complete solution you must provide more information as @Jim Garrison said.

The following code:

```
    String html ="<div class=\"Grid-u-1-2 Pend-xl\"><h3 class=\"My-xl Ta-c Fz-lg\"><a href=\"/hockey/27381/1\">Team One</a>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements names = doc.select("h3");
    for (Element e : names) {
        System.out.println(e.text());
    }
```

Gives me the expected output `Team One`. With no strange characters at all.

Hope it helps. Best regards.